# Java Netbeans Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have been using the youtube tutorial below in how to create and deal with Java Netbeans Hibernate. I have done exactly like in the video, but I get some errors in the end.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddoo6BUz4G4

The error message:

```
Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action '#(data.addMember())' with outcome '#(data.addMember())'
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Add User" action="#(data.addMember())"/>            
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Data.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.hibernate.Session;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Data {
    private Members m;
    private HibernateUtil helper;
    private Session session;

    public void addMember() {
        m = new Members("Steve");
        session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(m);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Members.java

```
public class Members {

    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String name;

    public Members(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

Members.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.Simon.Members" catalog="user" table="members">

      <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id">
          <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>

      <property name="name" type="string" column="name"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```